# Show first item in top navigation for mobile/tablet only in zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Is there a way how to show first link in top navigation just for mobile/tablets?

It would work OK if I would have "home" button in navigation, but I don't and that's the issue.

This is my code for menu. As you can see, first li should be visible only on mobiles and tablets.

```
<nav class="top-bar contain-to-grid">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">show on mobile/tablet only</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">third</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">fourth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">fifth</a></li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If in Zurb 4 (I've only looked at Zurb 4's docs), try adding class `show-for-small` to that first `<li>`

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html has all the different visibility classes listed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using by Standard:

visibility:hidden;

and then use:

@media queries for tablet, using:

visibility:visible;

Answer (score 0):

You use the class `show-for-medium-down` to show elements for mobile or tablet devices. So in your example, if you want to hide the first link in your navigation, you need to do this:

`<li class="show-for-medium-down"><a href="#">show on mobile/tablet only</a></li>`